# ListView_SetItemState not working as expected for only LVIS_FOCUSED

Tags: c, winapi

I feel like I'm just having one of those days and I'm ready to bang my head on the desk. Anyway, I'm trying to only set the LVIS_FOCUSED on a listview but it only appears to be working on Win2003 but not on Win7 nor Win11. The focus is set, but the focus outline is not displayed until you tab back around to it. My test program is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

#include "resource.h"

static LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message,
                                WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    LVITEM lvi;

    switch(message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        hWnd = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1);
        if (hWnd == NULL) return FALSE;

        lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
        lvi.iSubItem = 0;
        lvi.iItem = 0;
        lvi.pszText = TEXT("Hello");
        ListView_InsertItem(hWnd, &lvi);
        lvi.iItem = 1;
        lvi.pszText = TEXT("World");
        ListView_InsertItem(hWnd, &lvi);
        ListView_SetItemState(hWnd, 1, LVIS_FOCUSED,
            LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED);

        SetFocus(hWnd);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam) {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, 1);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   PSTR szcmdline, int iCmdShow) 
{
    DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        NULL, DlgProc);

    return 0;
}
```

resource.h has:

```
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     101
#define IDC_LIST1                       1001
```

and the dialog template is:

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 197, 95
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "ListView Test"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "List2",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_LIST | 
                    LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,7,
                    7,124,81
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,140,7,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,140,24,50,14
END
```

Specifically the problem is the word "World" will have a focus outline around it on Win2003, but on everything else, you won't see the focus outline until you tab 3 times.

That's the concern I have, but I did come across two other problems while creating this small example. The first is that I had to rearrange the tabstop so the OK button was not first, even though I have a SetFocus() for the listview in WM_INITDIALOG. The second is this will not run on WinXP. I get WM_SETFONT followed by WM_DESTROY. What's weird is my real program works on WinXP, but not this small example. Again, it's just been a long day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Focus rectangles are hidden by default, and pressing the Tab key reveals them. Perhaps your W2K3 machine has this option turned off?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed to go in the right direction to find WM_CHANGEUISTATE.

Comment: I had reproduced and am looking into this. Does the example work on WinXP? It should be noted that [WM_INITDIALOG should return FALSE to prevent the system from setting the default keyboard focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog#return-value).

Comment: Sorry, missed your reply. No the example still does not work on WinXP and I changed the return to FALSE and that didn't seem to make a difference. As I'm not having either of these problems with my application, I'm not really concerned about it. It had just made a long day longer that day.